# How to show if $\vdash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ then $\alpha \equiv \beta$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We know that $\alpha \equiv \beta$ if $\beta \vDash \alpha$ and $\alpha \vDash \beta$.

In first order logic:

$(M, v) \vDash \alpha$ iff $(M, v) \vDash \beta$ for every interpretation $(M, v)$.

But how to show starting from $\vdash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is a valid sentence. Assume that $(M,v)\models\alpha$, since $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is a valid sentence, it must be the case that $(M,v)\models\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$...

Continue from there.

Comment: Thanks, but why did you assume that if $\vdash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ then $(M, v) \vDash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$? From there, if I apply the definition of satisfiability it is quite simple to show that $\alpha \equiv \beta$.

Comment: You need to differentiate between $\leftrightarrow$ and $\equiv$. The former is a connective, so $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is a sentence; the latter, on the other hand, is a statement *about* sentences. Why did I assume that? Because if something is valid, it must be true in every interpretation.

Comment: I see now, thanks!